# Get id of an element through a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that is called in an onclick event in a checkbox field.

```
<input type='checkbox' checked='' onclick='return changeEnable();' id='someid'>
```

and the function

```
function changeEnable()
{
    var val = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(val);
}
```

I have that but it returns `undefined`. Is my syntax wrong or did I miss something?

Those checkboxes are dynamically created and have different id's, that's why I want to get the id for some task.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Note that `this` in your `changeEnable` function will be the `window`. You need to pass the reference to the element as a parameter to the function:

```
<input type='checkbox' checked='' onclick='return changeEnable(this);' id='someid'>
```

```js
function changeEnable(el) {
    var val = el.id
    alert(val);
}
```

Or, as an improvement, use Javascript to attach your events for a better separation of concerns:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="someid">
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('#someid').change(function() {
        var val = this.id
        alert(val);
    }
});
```

Note that the above uses the `change` event of the checkbox, which is better for accessibility reasons.

Comment: Wow. works perfect. Thanks for the reminder. I will select this answer after the timer :) Thank you!

Comment: Great answer, upvoted. For those new to JS (in this case JQuery) and wanting to use the JS events, for this scenario you obviously don't have the ID, so you'd want to assign a class to the generated inputs `<input type="checkbox" class="myInputClass">`, and use that `$('.myInputClass')`.

Answer (score 4):

i think this code will help u a lot

```
<input type='checkbox' checked='' onclick='return changeEnable(this);' id='someid'>`
```

```js
function changeEnable(thisobj)
{
    var val = thisobj.id;
    alert(val);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the parameter in the `changeEnable` function.

Comment: Thank you! If i could only select this as well.

Comment: Please explain why this will help.

Answer (score 3):

Also you should be aware of .call method which throws input context to function.

```
<input type='checkbox' checked='' onclick='changeEnable.call(this);' id='someid'>

function changeEnable()
{
    var val = this.id;
    alert(val);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use in this way:

```
<input type='checkbox' checked='' onclick='changeEnable(this);' id='someid'>
```

```js
function changeEnable(el)
{
    var val = el.id;
    alert(val);
}
```

Comment: Compare your answer with Rory's, who actually explains why the code works.